# Raw input or global hook to capture keystrokes?

Tags: c#, .net, capture, keystrokes

I have an application that captures keystrokes. But i have read a little bit about win7 problems that if the hook dont respond in a couple of seconds, the hook is terminated. And because of that some think Raw input is better. But i really dont know the difference about these 2.

What are the difference between them?
Can u capture shift/alt/ctrl presses in raw input?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in the past with global keyboard hooks which were getting unregistered. Adjusting the following value in the registry solved the problem:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"LowLevelHooksTimeout"=dword:00002710
```

Comment: So you just changed the "hexadecimal" value from xxx to 2710 and that worked? Have you thought about using Raw input?

Comment: Yes, this has worked for me. I haven't thought of using Raw input.

Comment: I will try that out, but have u tried capturing data with "raw input" ?

Comment: Hmm ok, i will try it , but i have read alot of people changing from global hooks to raw input because of the direct response , and it wont "disconnect" and so on...